# RGB565 to Grayscale

Tags: c, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I am trying to convert an RGB565 to the Grayscale image.

I used the below code to do the conversion. I have a rgb565 pixel. I am getting R,G and B values and doing the conversion operation. Once the grayscale is obtained, I am reconstructing a 16 bit pixel values wherein R, G and B will have the same grayscale value.

```
 int16_t pixel = *buffer;
 int16_t red = ((pixel & 0xF800)>>11);
 int16_t green = ((pixel & 0x07E0)>>5);
 int16_t blue = (pixel & 0x001F);
 int16_t grayscale = (0.2126 * red) + (0.7152 * green) + (0.0722 * blue);
 *buffer=(grayscale<<11)+(grayscale<<5)+grayscale;
```

Here, I expected a grayscale image. However, what is happening is ->

Green color has 6 bits of space (has more magnitude). The resulting grayscale value should be 5bits so that, i will fit for R G and B. However, the calculation done provides a 6 bit grayscale because of which I am not getting a proper grayscale image.

Could anyone help me to convert a rgb565 to grayscale and store it as 16 bits.

Comment: The `grayscale` value you got from calculation is 3 times bigger of the final field to assign. Moreover the R and B components have half scale with respect to G. Try scaling it as ` *buffer=(((grayscale/2)/3)<<11)+((grayscale/3)<<5)+(grayscale/2)/3;` first of all

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But, I do not understand the concept behind your scaling? Could you explain me?

Comment: @Frankie_C I don't understand your comment neither.

Comment: @SindujaPrakash a fast computaion shows that `grayscale`value can go until 53 more or less. So it cannot be coded on 5 bits. Your black and white conversion formula does not seem to take into account that `green`has not the same representation / magnitude than `red`and `blue`. You should probably divide `green`by 2 before computing  `grayscale`

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Thank you for the help! I also tried neglecting the LSB of green color. Do you think that is another good possible solution?

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment, you only need to scale the two components R and B as `*buffer=((grayscale/2)<<11)+(grayscale<<5)+grayscale/2;`. Consider the pure green color=0x7E0, after conversion grayscale=45=0x2D. that is 6 bits wide. Assigning it to R and B components it will overflow, as @GuillaumePetitjean also advised you can simply divide green before conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Green` component have 6 bit, not because it needs to have higher values but because it needs higher resolution (see [RGB 565 - Why 6 Bits for Green Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467682/rgb-565-why-6-bits-for-green-color)).

So to bring the value range to equal that of `Red` and `Blue`, just divide the `Green` value by 2:

```
 int16_t pixel = *buffer;
 int16_t red = ((pixel & 0xF800)>>11);
 int16_t green = ((pixel & 0x07E0)>>5);
 int16_t blue = (pixel & 0x001F);
 int16_t grayscale = (0.2126 * red) + (0.7152 * green / 2.0) + (0.0722 * blue);
 //                                                   ^^^^^
 *buffer=(grayscale<<11)+(grayscale<<6)+grayscale;
```

Comment: You also need to multiply the green component by 2 in the output buffer (or just change the `<<5` to `<<6`).

Comment: Thanks for the help! It indeed worked !! And yah (changed to <<6) as @IanAbbott mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think Pibben's answer still has some shift/mask bugs in it, and it uses floating point which, depending on your environment, could range from abysmally slow to not even possible.  I had done this myself some time ago, so here is what I wrote up:

The first thing I wanted is a monochrome viewfinder mode...  I want to work in 16-bit integer space, for speed,
so I need to use standard fixed-point scaled math.  Starting with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems, which uses coefficients that work with
gamma-corrected values:

> Y = 0.2126×R + 0.7152×G + 0.0722×B

Given R<sub>MAX</sub> = G<sub>MAX</sub> = B<sub>MAX</sub> = 63, a scale
factor of 1000 will avoid overflowing a U16.  So, we have to lose the
LSD of the given four-digit coefficients.  To avoid division by 1000
after the summation we can scale all factors up by 1024/1000, then our
division becomes a right-shift by 10 bits.  So for our coefficients:
(2126×1024)÷10000 = 217.7, rounded to 218.  Etc.  Given
these calculated coefficients and RGB565 source format,
Y<sub>MAX</sub> = 64,220, which does not
overflow a U16; check.  Divided by 1024 the maximum result is 62.7,
which can be rounded to 63; Perfect.  (Rounding is simply adding back
the most-significant bit lost in the shift, something that is usually
nearly trivial in assembly language [add 0 with carry] but somewhat
messier in C.)  That gives us a 0..63 6-bit integer luminance value
that is easy to pack back into RGB565.  The final de-colorization code
becomes:

```
void
decolorize(U16 *usp, int count)
{
   U16 us, rc, gc, bc, luma;

   while (--count) {
      us = *usp;
      rc = (us >> 10) & 0x3E; /* 6-bit Red Component. */
      gc = (us >> 5) & 0x3F;  /* 6-bit Green Component. */
      bc = (us << 1) & 0x3E;  /* 6-bit Blue Component. */
      luma = (rc * 218) + (gc * 732) + (bc * 74); /* Wx*1024/10000. */
      luma = (luma >> 10) + ((luma >> 9) & 1); /* 6-bit Luminance value. */
     *usp++ = ((luma & 0x3E) << 10) | (luma << 5) | (luma >> 1); /* RGB565 */
   }
}
```

Moreover, if you can afford a 128kB lookup table, initialized by code similar to above, the RGB565 pixels can be translated directly by array lookup, which is pretty fast on most processors.  I don't think you can beat this for speed unless you are using a GPU, or a vector processor.  The LUT is how I ended up actually using this code.