# Reduce Image bit C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

How can I reduce  the number of bits from 24 bits to a number between 0 and 8 bits and  distribute the bits for the three colors Red, Green and Blue

Any idea ?

Comment: you could have at most 2 bits per color, two for red, two for green, two for blue. You would have two bits left. You need to use bitwise operations to unpack the 24 bit values into 8 bits

Comment: I want to use any number from 0 to 8 for a color to give, for example I give red 6 bits, green and blue 1 bit and so on

Comment: Just FYI... it is fairly common to reduce to 16-bits of colour which gives rise to things like RGB565. Nice discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468070/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "Color Quantization". You have 16.777.216 colors and you want to map them to a smaller number (2 to 256).

Step 1: choose the colors you want to use. First their number, then the colors themselves. You need to chose if the colors are fixed for all images, or if they change based on the image (you will need to ship a palette of colors with every image).

Step 2: substitute the colors of your image with those in the selection.

If the colors are fixed and you want to stay *very* simple you can use 1 bit per channel (8 colors in total) or 2 bits per channel (64 colors in total).

Slightly more complex, use these values for each channel 0, 51, 102, 153, 204, 255, in any possible way, leading to 216 different color combinations. Make a table which associates every color combination with an index. That index requires 8 bits (with some spare). This is called a "web safe palette" (this brings me back to the late 1999). Now you are ready for substitution: take every pixel in your image and the quantized color can be found as `x*6//256*51` (`//` is integer division).

If you want a better looking palette, look for the [Median cut algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_cut).

Answer (score 0):

Keep only the most significant bits of the pixel's red channel. Do likewise for the green and blue channel. Then use C++'s bit manipulation operations to move those bits values into a single byte. There are multiple ways of doing so. For example, do an Internet search for "rgb332" for one example (where you keep 3 red bits, 3 green bits, and 2 blue bits).

Comment: I want to make the user enter the value of bit system for each color, can I?

Comment: bit_r , bit_g , bit_b  
cin>>bit_r >> bit_g >> bit_b
//something like that

Comment: Yes, you certainly could choose to use 6 of the bits for red, and only 1 bit each for green and blue (if those are levels of precision that are appropriate for your particular application). One byte has 8 bits of storage available, and since you are the programmer who's writing the bit shifting operations that pack 6+1+1=8 bits of information into 8 bit positions, you can choose to allocate your 8 bit positions that way if you want to.